# How do I recycle batteries in Argentina?

Tags: recycling, batteries

I have dead batteries and I want to know the best way to dispose of them, ideally by recycling. Here in Argentina there is almost nowhere to take them. We just put them in the garbage.

Comment: It seems there are [no (official) battery recycling programs in Argentina](http://www.dw.de/buenos-aires-struggles-with-its-recycling-system/a-16104113), but it looks like [steps are being taken to fix this](http://www.complianceandrisks.com/argentina-proposes-national-law-on-the-management-of-waste-batteries-and-accumulators/). Perhaps you could speed things up by starting a petition that you want such a program in your local community?

Comment: I asked an argentinien colleague. He keeps them in a box and wants to know the answer too.

Comment: @THelper Why don't you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Earthliŋ because I was hoping someone would prove me wrong and provide an answer that there actually is a recycling program. Also I am not sure about the best alternative. Shipping to a country where they can be recycled? Trying to recycle yourself? Burying the batteries (as was proposed in [this question](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/2995/99))?

Answer (score 2):

My Spanish isn't great, but I think that on the website of [this Argentinian recycling company called Silkers SA](http://www.silkers.com.ar/gestion-ecologica-de-baterias) they are saying that you should:

1. Check the website of the producer of the battery if they accept it back.
2. Check this [webpage of the city of Buenos Aires](http://www.buenosaires.gob.ar/areas/med_ambiente/apra/des_sust/res_esp/empresa_recoleccion.php?razonsocial=3&barrio)  (however, this link reports "service unavailable" and "Sitio en Mantenimiento" at the time of writing)
3. Check the website http://www.dondereciclo.org.ar

This last website also has a [blog in Spanish on batteries](http://www.dondereciclo.org.ar/blog/las-pilas-te-las-pones-cuando-no-las-usas/). If I understand the blog correctly it says that there is a law which prohibits the use of mercury, cadmium and lead in non-rechargable batteries so they can be handled as 'normal' waste !?

Rechargable batteries on the other hand are collected in various places in Buenos Aires, but according to [this map](https://www.dondereciclo.org.ar/pilas-recargables) also in Rosario and Cordoba